# How can I define APPEND for Rebol3 PORT?

Tags: append, rebol, rebol3

I'm working on scheme in Rebol3 and I'd like to add APPEND action. However, adding APPEND actor to the scheme does nothing, result of `append my-scheme://localhost foobar` is `my-scheme://localhostfoobar` instead of my action. The [documentation](http://www.rebol.net/wiki/Schemes%3aNotes#Series_Actions) is bit unfinished in this regard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use append on the port, and not the url!

```
port: open my-scheme://localhost
append port "my data"
```

The only port actors that can take a URL as an argument are those that have a port! specified as an argument.  These are create, delete, open, close, read, write, open?, query, update, and rename.  See http://www.rebol.net/wiki/Schemes:Notes#Port_Actions